# Servo motor reacts to other things

Tags: arduino

I am working with Arduino, I connected a servo motor and a normal motor. They both work but when I start the normal motor script, the servo motor does small spastic stuff.
Could anyone help me with this?

```
    // Includes
#include <Servo.h> 

// Aanmaken van de variabelen voor in de code

int ledPin = 13;
const int motorPin = 2;
int usbnumber = 0;
Servo stuurServo;   // create servo object to control a servo 
int pos = 90;        // variable to store the servo position 


// De eerste setup maken
void setup()
{
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
    stuurServo.attach(12);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    stuurServo.write(pos);
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        usbnumber = Serial.read();

    }

    if (usbnumber > 0) {
        if (usbnumber == 1){ // Lampje knipperen
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
            delay(1000);
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
            delay(1000);
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
            delay(1000);
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
            delay(500);
        }else if(usbnumber == 2){ // Motor aan voor 5 seconden
            digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
            delay(20000);
            digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
        }else if(usbnumber == 3){ // stuur servo +10 graden
            if(pos != 180){
              pos + 10;
              stuurServo.write(pos);
            }
        }else if(usbnumber == 4){ // stuur servo -10 graden
            if(pos != 0){
              pos - 10;
             stuurServo.write(pos);
            }
        }else if(usbnumber == 5){ // stuur servo liks
             pos = 0;
             stuurServo.write(pos);
        }else if(usbnumber == 6){ // stuur servo rechts
             pos = 180;
             stuurServo.write(pos);
        }else{
            delay(500);
        }
        usbnumber = 0;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Define: Does small spastic stuff?

Comment: These are always tough to troubleshoot without seeing your schematic, however depending on the motor and at what speed you are running it, it can cause feedback noise in the lines that will affect the servo motor.  Try adding a filter to your regular motor line and see if that helps.

Comment: Why this question have PHP tag marked?

Comment: How are you powering the motor + servo.

Comment: Do you realise that while you delay 5 seconds inside the loop no serial data can be obtained? Id start by changing the serial reading to `while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        usbnumber = Serial.read();

    }` to consume the entire buffer (and use only the last command) BTW: what does Serial.read() return, an int , a string, or a character ?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have a similar issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most (hobby) servo motors will twitch or give a little jerk when they are powered up, especially if you power the motor before driving the servo (providing a position control signal). The solution is to write to the control line to the servo before allowing power to it. Some easy solutions include:

1. controlling power to the servo through something you can turn off/on (PWM, MOSFET someone else help here?)
2. having a secondary power manual switch you can toggle once your controller is up and running.

There is basically nothing you can do in code without some way to have the circuit start up with no power to the Servo until you are driving the position control line.